# What is the difference between command1 && command2 and command1 & command2 in Linux cmd, to execute chain commands?

Tags: linux, unix

What is the difference between **command1 && command2**    and    **command1 & command2**  in Linux cmd while executing the chain commands.

Comment: & is the bitwise AND operator, && is the logical AND operator

Comment: @Hugo, in shell, `&` is the run-in-background terminator, not bitwise-and.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&&` is a logical AND operator, so in the first case `command1` is started and if it succeeds (returns with exit status of 0) then `command2` will run.

`&` is an operator in bash/shell that starts the command backgrounded, so in the second case `command1` is started in the background then (without waiting for it to finish) `command2` is started.